# Is my understanding and presentation of concept of Gradient Boosting correct?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, ensemble-learning, gradient

Initially the model is trained with a training set $\{x_{i}, y_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ by minimizing a differentiable loss function $L(y, F(x))$, and, is initialized with a constant value,

\begin{align*}
F_{0}(x) = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_\gamma \sum_{i=1}^{n}
L(y_{i},\gamma)
\end{align*}

Then from iteration 1 to *M* a pseudo-residual is computed in every iteration as follows,

\begin{align*}
r_{i,m} = - \left[ \frac{\partial L(y_{i}, F(x_{i}))}{\partial F(x_{i})}\right]_{F(x) = F_{m-1}(x)}\hspace{0.25cm}for\hspace{0.25cm}i = 1,.....,n\hspace{0.25cm} \\ and\hspace{0.25cm} m\hspace{0.25cm} is\hspace{0.25cm} the\hspace{0.25cm} iteration\hspace{0.25cm} number\hspace{0.25cm} and\hspace{0.25cm} n\hspace{0.25cm} is\hspace{0.25cm} the\hspace{0.25cm} number\hspace{0.25cm} of\hspace{0.25cm} samples\hspace{0.25cm} in\hspace{0.25cm} y\hspace{0.25cm}.
\end{align*}
Next, a base learner $h_{m}$ is trained with the training set $\{x_{i}, r_{i,m}\}_{i=1}^{n}$. Multiplier $\gamma_{m}$ is computed such that,

\begin{align*}
\gamma_{m} = \operatorname*{arg\,min}_\gamma \sum_{i=1}^{n}L(y_{i}, F_{m-1}(x_{i}) + \gamma h_{m}(x_{i}))
\end{align*}

Then, the model is updated as follows,

\begin{align*}
F_{m}(x) = F_{m-1}(x) + \gamma_{m}h_{m}(x)
\end{align*}

This process continues for *M* number of iterations. The final model $F_{M}$ is output at the end of  *M th* iteration.

Comment: yes its understood right

Comment: thank you......